# How to construct a nest object programmatically

Tags: javascript

```
{ 
  '$or': [ 
           { adv_id: 3 }, 
           { adv_id: 3 } 
         ] 
}
```

Anyone know how to construct this type of Object programmatically in Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean exactly. You could just assign that to a variable:

```
var object = { 
  '$or': [ 
     { adv_id: 3 }, 
     { adv_id: 3 } 
  ] 
}
```

Or, step by step:

```
var object = {};
object.$or = [];
object.$or[0] = {};
object.$or[1] = {};
object.$or[0].adv_id = 3;
object.$or[1].adv_id = 3;
```

Comment: Your next code block is what I want. Thanks!